# HTML - FORM Empty File Field gives (binary) as data at server side

Tags: html, forms, multipartform-data, form-data

I've a `<form>` like below:

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="file" size=64>

<p>
or paste your Data here:
</p>

<textarea name="data" cols="80" rows="30" wrap="soft">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

When I submit the form as empty form at server side I see `file` field is having value as `(binary)`. Any idea why this is happening?

Also I've observed that **this happens only when you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as attribute in your `<form>`**.

Here is output of network tab from browser dev tools.

[image: Here is screen shot of formdata params]

Comment: When you send a file it is sent as binary data, on your server you will need to do something with that binary, (copy to a local file, upload to s3, whatever you need to do with it)

Comment: @Art3mix, I'm not sending any file in this case. I just hit submit without any data. Still In `file` field I get it as `(binary)`.

Comment: Empty still will be represented as empty but in binary, it simply tells you that field is in binary

Answer (score 1):

Sending files with HTML forms is a special case. Files are binary data — or considered as such — whereas all other data is text data. Because HTTP is a text protocol, there are special requirements for handling binary data.

Comment: What about the form being empty?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Empty still need to know what type of empty data is sent. This allows you to know that empty $_FILES data is sent as oppose to empty $_POST.

Comment: So what would be the difference if I uploaded no file or I uploaded an empty file?

Comment: An empty file would be considered a file. If you didn't upload a file, the $_FILES would be empty. You can test these things by doing <?php print_r($_FILES);?> and see what happens when you submit. Put in script.php. Also do the same with $_POST. You will understand the differences of those variables when submitted.